# What made Sekiguchi embarrassed when she was asked about cram school?

Tags: nichijou

In episode 6, there is a scene where Daiku, a former team member of Igo soccer, is getting bored with their inactivity in their club room. The conversation follows like this (read from left to right):

[image: Daiku: And you'reno fun, Sekiguchi]
[image: Daiku: Don't you go to cram school, Sekiguchi?]
[image: ... Sekiguchi with embarassed f ace]
[image: Daiku: You're joking]

> Daiku: Oh come on, everyone said they had cram school and left...
>   Daiku: And you're no fun, Sekiguchi
>   *Sekiguchi is reading a book silently*
>   Daiku: Don't you go to cram school, Sekiguchi?
>   *Sekiguchi flips a page, looks at Daiku, then continues reading the book silently while being embarrassed*
>   *Daiku stares at Sekiguchi*
>   *Sekiguchi is getting more embarrassed*
>   Daiku: You're joking!

Why was Daiku surprised all of sudden?

Relevant video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfVlQBSex0U)

Comment: I think you're one of those oblivious guy :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

She skipped cram school so that she could stay at the club. When he, being the last person left, asked about it and she blushed it implies she has a crush on him and wanted to spend time specially with him, he realised this and was shocked  *~ooh young love*